# changing vb.net chart xAxis maximum and minimum datetime type

Tags: vb.net, datetime, charts, visual-studio-2017

I am using chart control on vb.net windows form application.

I am loading data into `chart1` and all looks good; I am using this data type:

```
Chart1.Series("test").XValueType = DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.DateTime
Chart1.Series("test").YValueType = DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Int32
```

Then I am using a `Trackbar1` control to change/zoom/rescale **`xAxis`** and using this code:

```
Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Scroll
        ChartRanger(TrackBar1.Value)
End Sub
```

Having `TrackBar1` min=0 and max=366 in Property window.

While the `ChartRanger` function looks like this:

```
Private Sub ChartRanger(theDays As Integer)
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IntervalType = 0
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 0
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = 0
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = theDays
End Sub
```

There is no debugging error and it looks like working; but the logic is not correct in the output.

**i.e.** What I am trying to achieve is to let app user define `minimum` datetime and `maximum` datetime for `chart1` **xAxis**. having dataset contains a daily records.

**Update:** I have seen the other related posts, they suggest answers for ASP, VBA but can't find answer for VB.Net win forms; its more for the best logic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is `Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = theDays`. The AxisX type is a Double representing a DateTime, while `theDays` is an Integer. You need to figure out what the maximum date for `AxisX` should be based on the value of `theDays`, and convert that date to a double using `ToOADate()`.

Here's a working example:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Chart1.Series.Clear()

        Dim s = Chart1.Series.Add("s")

        s.ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Point

        s.XValueType = DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.DateTime
        s.XValueType = DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Int32


        For i As Integer = 0 To 100
            s.Points.AddXY(Date.Today.AddDays(i), i)
        Next

        TrackBar1.Maximum = 100
    End Sub

    Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Scroll
        Dim val As Integer = TrackBar1.Value
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = Date.Today.AddDays(val).ToOADate()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Or if you don't know the min and max dates already, you can set the axis maximum relative to the position of the TrackBar:

```
Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Scroll

    ' Get min and max dates
    Dim maxDate As Date = Date.FromOADate(Chart1.Series("s").Points.FindMaxByValue("X").XValue)
    Dim minDate As Date = Date.FromOADate(Chart1.Series("s").Points.FindMinByValue("X").XValue)

    ' Get total days between dates
    Dim totalDays = maxDate.Subtract(minDate).Days

    ' Get the bar position as a percent of 100
    Dim barPct As Double = TrackBar1.Value / TrackBar1.Maximum

    ' Find the maximum day that should be displayed on the plot
    Dim maxAxisDay As Integer = barPct * totalDays

    ' Get the date of the maximum day
    Dim maxAxisDate = minDate.AddDays(maxAxisDay)

    ' Set maximum. Convert the date to a double using .ToOADate()
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = maxAxisDate.ToOADate()
End Sub
```

Edit:
Assuming that the trackbar maximum is set to the total number of days represented by the dataset, it's a bit easier:

```
  Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Scroll
        ' Get the first date
        Dim minDate As Date = Date.FromOADate(Chart1.Series("s").Points.FindMinByValue("X").XValue)

        ' Assuming that the trackbar has the total number of days represented, the maximum date to display is the first date plus the 
        ' days represented by the trackbar
        Dim maxDisplayDate As Date = minDate.AddDays(TrackBar1.Value)

        ' Set the max axis
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = maxDisplayDate.ToOADate()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @LeopoldVonBuschLight, The chart's data is accumulated. ie. maximum date is today, and lots of old dated data. I can get the oldest data datetime

Comment: Does the second code block help any? Do the TrackBar ticks need to represent single days or just a relative position?

Comment: the second block looks very promising and yes, assume a daily logged data to be charted. so a single day for each tick, appreciated your efforts, Thank you

Comment: See the third edit. You'll have to make sure that the trackbar maximum is set to the days represented by the dataset.

Comment: Thank you, the dataset contains such: Monday, Tuesday , Wednesday, Thursday while today date is Thursday....its in reverse old to Today(max available date).

Comment: Thank you @Leopold, saved my day , 5 stars, **indeed the third edit did the trick**.